# Templates that #define for Python

Tags: python, templates, macros, template-engine

Which of the many templating frameworks should I use to be able to use simple macros like this in Python? Basic macros seem to be all I need, and the amount of frameworks available is overwhelming.

```
#define R(a,b,c,k) as b ^= (a + c) << k
R(x[ 0], x[ 4], x[12], 7)
R(x[ 5], x[ 9], x[ 1], 7)
```

It would resolve into something like this (math-code):

```
x[ 4] ⊕= (x[ 0] ⊞ x[12])<<<7;    
x[ 9] ⊕= (x[ 5] ⊞ x[ 1])<<<7;
```

Comment: Python doesn't have macros so it won't change the code. If you want the outcome to be a string then most template engines will work (e.g., jinja2). If you want macros then perhaps function calls work best here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into Jinja2 as Simeon suggested. It looks very handy, and has macros too!
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#macros